# Verificar ID antes de registrarlo en BD

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Necesito un poco de ayudaa :(, estoy recién practicando estas consultas y tengo un problema al momento de verificar la existencia de un ID (rut) antes de registrarlo en mi base de datos... pero el filtro no funciona :[

Este es mi código:

```
$votador = $_POST['rut'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM votante WHERE rut = '$votador'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >= 1) {

  echo "El rut ya existe.";

}else{

  $sql = "INSERT INTO votante VALUES (NULL,'".$_POST['rut']."')";

  $result = mysql_query($sql);

  if (! $result){

    echo "La consulta SQL contiene errores.".mysql_error();

    exit();

  }else{

      header('Location: votaciones.php');
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el error que te da?

Comment: Primero, donde haces la consulta para el select? mandas a llamar una variable `$result` que aun no existe o no contiene nada...

Comment: @Oswuell, solamente registra los datos en la BD y me muestra la pagina de destino, pero no me verifica si existe o no :/

Comment: Es que tienes una variable `$result´ que no contiene nada.

Comment: Hay un problema serio en tu código, por una parte usas la vieja extensión para conectar a la base de datos: son todas las funciones que empiezan así: `mysql_` y por otra parte usas `mysqli`, son todas las llamadas que haces con el estilo orientado a objetos usando `->` Antes que nada iguala todo tu código a la extensión `mysqli`. Si la parte que te funciona es **la parte vieja**, significa que te estás conectado al estilo viejo, y el código de verificación no funcionará jamás porque está escrito al estilo nuevo (el cual es recomendable). ¿Cómo creas la conexión?

Comment: ¿estás seguro que existe el campo llamado `rut` en la tabla `votante` de la base de datos?

Comment: A nivel de diseño, opino que es mucho mejor **no hacer la comprobación y dejar que falle si ya está**. Hacer la comprobación antes no te da nada (al fin y al cabo acabas mostrando un error) y siempre hay la posibilidad de que entre la comprobación y el `insert` alguna otra petición introduzca ese id, así que de todas formas tendrás que comprobar ese posible fallo. Y lo normal es que el `id` no coincida; si hay riesgo de que pase (por ejemplo un usuario escoge su login) el usuario debería saber si el `id` está cogido **antes de validar el form**.